# Nestjs custom file validator for Multer middleware

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I've been following the Nestjs documentation for custom file validator implementations and I've written my custom class:

```
import { FileValidator } from './FileValidator.class';

interface ImageSizeValidationOptions {
  maxSize: number;
}

export class ImageSizeValidator extends FileValidator<ImageSizeValidationOptions> {
  constructor(validationOptions: { maxSize: number }) {
    super(validationOptions);
  }
  isValid(file?: Express.Multer.File): boolean {
    if (!file) return false;
    const { maxSize } = this.validationOptions;
    const fileSize = file.size;
    return fileSize < maxSize;
  }
  buildErrorMessage(file: any): string {
    const { maxSize } = this.validationOptions;
    return `Image must be less than ${maxSize}KB`;
  }
}
```

that extends the given FileValidator class given by Nestjs:

```
export abstract class FileValidator<TValidationOptions = Record<string, any>> {
  constructor(protected readonly validationOptions: TValidationOptions) {}

  /**
   * Indicates if this file should be considered valid, according to the options passed in the constructor.
   * @param file the file from the request object
   */
  abstract isValid(file?: any): boolean | Promise<boolean>;

  /**
   * Builds an error message in case the validation fails.
   * @param file the file from the request object
   */
  abstract buildErrorMessage(file: any): string;
}
```

but when I add it to my controller that's responsible for uploads:

```
import {
  Controller,
  HttpStatus,
  ParseFilePipe,
  ParseFilePipeBuilder,
  Post,
  UploadedFile,
  UseInterceptors,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AwsService } from './aws.service';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { ImageSizeValidator } from './types/ImageSizeValidator.class';

@Controller('aws')
export class AwsController {
  constructor(private awsService: AwsService) {}

  @Post('s3-upload')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  uploadFile(
    @UploadedFile(
      new ParseFilePipe({
        validators: [
            new ImageSizeValidator({maxSize: 1000})
        ]
      })
    )
    file: Express.Multer.File,
  ) {
    return this.awsService.upload(file);
  }
}
```

I get the following type error:

```
Type 'ImageSizeValidator' is not assignable to type 'FileValidator<Record<string, any>, IFile>'.
  Property 'validationOptions' is protected but type 'FileValidator<TValidationOptions>' is not a class derived from 'FileValidator<TValidationOptions, TFile>'.ts(2322)
```

I understand I'm missing the file type but it's not shown as necessary in the abstract class given by Nestjs.

Could someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I understand that your code is not using the `FileValidator` class declaration you provided, but [this one](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/pipes/file/file-type.validator.ts) instead. Can you provide some kind of `IFile` in this case?

Comment: I am using the FileValidator class I provided, the one given in the documentation